# How to check if my Rails app really creates Guest Users in Devise (rails/devise/cancan)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have set up devise for my app then i've used this to enable guest users: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

I tested my signin/out and it still seems to work. **I actually wonder if it's really creating guest users**. How can I check it's actually really creating guest users when anonymous users connect?

Comment: Great question. A better question: how to test this *using a testing framework* :)

Answer (score 0):

Just open up rails console `rails c` in terminal, and then query your database `User.where(name: 'guest')`. You should have a list of guest users back if it's working.